# Ldap insertion exception

Tags: java, ldap

I am trying add an entry to a directory server database. These are the values i am inserting:

```
userName=[ben@gmail.com]
driverEmail=[ben@gmail.com]
driverPassword=[ben]
firstName=[Ben]
lastName=[Hur]
newsletter=[false]
```

And i am getting this exception:

```
SEVERE: Cannot create new LDAP entry
LDAPException(resultCode=object class violation, errorMessage='Entry mwUniqueIdentifier=5f9e7597-8a5f-42b0-985b-7d196040689e,ou=People,dc=mobilewarrio
r,dc=com violates the Directory Server schema configuration because it includes     multiple conflicting structural objectclasses inetOrgPerson and mwUser
Account.  Only a single structural objectclass is allowed in an entry')
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong in it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't show exactly how you're going about inserting those values, so it's hard to be too specific. However, the exception is pretty clear.

You tried to assign the entry both the `inetOrgPerson` object class and the `mwUser` object class, which doesn't work as they are both defined as structural object classes and neither inherits from the other (most likely `mwUser` is defined as a structural object class because your schema did not specify it as a `AUXILIARY` or `ABSTRACT` object class).

Per [RFC 4512](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4512#section-2.4.2):

> An object or alias entry is characterized by precisely one structural object class superclass chain which has a single structural object class as the most subordinate object class.

There are two possible fixes which should involve simple changes to your LDAP schema:

1. If you intend all `mwUser` objects to be `inetOrgPerson` objects, simply declare `mwUser` a sub-object class of `inetOrgPerson` like so (taken from [the OpenLDAP documentation](http://www.openldap.org/doc/admin22/schema.html)):

   objectclass ( 1.1.2.2.2 NAME 'myPerson'
   DESC 'my person'
   SUP inetOrgPerson
   MUST ( myUniqueName $ givenName )
   MAY myPhoto )

In this situation, you will only need to assign the `mwUser` object class to your entry.

2. If you do not want all `mwUser` objects to be `inetOrgPerson` objects, then declare it a mixin by specifying that it is an auxiliary object class like so:

   objectclass ( 1.1.2.2.1 NAME 'myPhotoObject'
   DESC 'mixin myPhoto'
   AUXILIARY
   MAY myPhoto )

In this situation, you will have to assign both the `inetOrgPerson` (or another structural object class) as well as the `mwUser` object class to the object.